# How to decide whether to use Bayes' theorem or not?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, bayes-theorem

> A bag contains 12 red balls  and 6 white balls. Six balls are drawn one by one without replacement of which at least 4 balls are white. Find the probability that in next two drawn , exactly one white ball is drawn. ( Leave answer in $ \binom{n}{r}$)

What I did:

$$ P = \frac{\binom{6}{4} \binom{12}{2}}{\binom{18}{6}}  \frac{\binom{2}{1} \binom{10}{1}}{\binom{12}{2}}+  \frac{\binom{6}{5} \binom{12}{1}}{\binom{18} {6}} \frac{\binom{1}{1} \binom{11}{1}}{\binom{12}{2}} +  \frac{\binom{6}{6} \binom{12}{0}}{\binom{18}{6}} \cdot 0$$

The idea behind this: so the first factor in each term of sum, is the probability for a number of white ball- red ball combination to be drawn and the factor multiplied with it is the probability for drawing one white ball from the remaining pool.

However the solution key says,

$$ P= \frac{\binom{12}{2}\binom{6}{4} \binom{10}{1} \binom{2}{1} + \binom{12}{1} \binom{6}{5} \binom{11}{1}\binom{1}{1} }{\binom{12}{2} ( \binom{12}{2} \binom{6}{4} + \binom{12}{1} \binom{6}{5} + \binom{12}{0} \binom{6}{6})}$$

This seems to be some sort of Bayes' theorem application but I can't really see why we would need Bayseian thinking here.

Comment: Well, you know that, initially, you drew one of $4,5,6$ white balls. You have to compute the probability of each case and, for each case, compute the probability that exactly one of the next two draws is also white.

Comment: right, so solution key is wrong right?

Comment: I didn't say that.  Be careful:  you are after the probability that you drew exactly $4$ (or $5$ or $6$) $\textit {conditioned on}$ the fact that you drew at least $4$.  I don't see where you used that conditioning.

Comment: Your approach looks to be computing the probability that at least 4 white balls were drawn in the first 6 draws and then exactly one white ball is drawn in the next two balls drawn after that. The solution key is the probability that exactly one ball drawn from 2 draws is white **given** at least 4 of the first 6 balls drawn were white.

Comment: so, if I got this right the question is not asking probability that you draw one white ball under the constraint of white balls being drawn but rather under the hypothesis that so and so white balls being drawn what is chance of white ball being drawn?

Comment: How does one figure out whether to condition or not to condition

Comment: @Buraian "of which" is the key phrase that identifies this as a conditional statement.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZGCoVF3YvM

Comment: @DanielS. That is 4 ads per click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a formula: Suppose we have $R$ red balls & $W$ white balls, then the probability of selecting a **specific** sequence of $r $ red balls & $w $ white balls (with $r \le R, w \le W$) is
$ { (R+W - (r+w))! \over (R+W)!} { R! \over (R-r)! } {W! \over (W-w)! }$. Since these can
be rearranged in $\binom{w+r}{w}$ ways, we see that the probability of selecting $r $ red balls & $w $ white balls (in any order) is
$p((R,W),(r,w)) = \binom{w+r}{w} { (R+W - (r+w))! \over (R+W)!} { R! \over (R-r)! } {W! \over (W-w)! } = {1 \over \binom{W+R}{w+r} }\binom{W}{w} \binom{R}{r}$.

Let $B$ be the event that the $7$th and $8$th draw have exactly one white ball.
Let $A_k$ be the event that exactly $k$ white balls are drawn in the first $6$ draws.
Let $A= A_4 \cup A_5 \cup A_6$ (disjoint union).

We want to compute $P[B|A] = {P[B \cap A] \over P[A] } = {P[B \cap A_4]+P[B \cap A_5]+p[B \cap A_6] \over P[A_4]+P[A_5]+P[A_6]} = {P[B|A_4]P[A_4]+P[B|A_5]P[A_5]+p[B|A_6]P[A_6] \over P[A_4]+P[A_5]+P[A_6]} $.

Note that $P[B|A_k] = p((10+(k-4),2-(k-4)),(1,1))$.

Substituting we get
$P[B|A]= { p((10,2),(1,1)) p((12,6),(2,4))+p((11,1),(1,1)) p((12,6),(1,5))+p((12,0),(1,1)) p((12,6),(0,6)) \over p((12,6),(2,4))+p((12,6),(1,5))+p((12,6),(0,6))} $.

Substituting for $p$ gives the solution key answer above.